# counting non-unique sub-multisets of a set.

Tags: combinatorics, multisets

Thank you all for your replies. I am so sorry for the inconvenience, I think I have messed up a lot in here.

I'll just rephrase the whole question again.
Let N be the original set which follows the conventional set definition of not having duplicates.
What I am trying to find is the number of multi-sets of length C, where all of their elements ∈ N.

The length is define as the number of the elements in the multi-set including the repeated ones. N is composed of integers only.

Since I am not so good with symbols, I'll put a numerical example:
Let N = {1, 2, 3, 4} and C = 7, a possible multi-set is  x = {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5}
, where the length of x = 7. There is no constrain on the number of repetition as long as the length of x is <= C.

The sets {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5} and {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5} are not included since both have a length that is > 7.

There is no limit on C i.e. it can be bigger than the size of N.

I am also not interested in the permutations of the sets, so: 
{1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5}, {1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 5}, {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 4} etc.. are all the same.

Comment: A set, by definition, contains every element only *once*. So I'm not exactly sure what you mean with non-unique: are you thinking of permutations of a set?

Comment: @Newb: There's a concept of multisets.

Comment: By that logic, {2,2,2,4} is a valid subset, and so is {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4}. There would be infinitely many. By the way the correct term here is [multisets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset).

Comment: @user4894 {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4} size is bigger than the size of N so it is not valid, and sorry about using the wrong word, and no I don't care about the permutations of the sets.

Comment: Are you curious about order?  Is $\{2,2,4\}$ considered the same as $\{2,4,2\}$?

Comment: They are the same

Comment: The way you have defined things above seems akward.  I think you are interested in $|\mathcal{F}|$ where $\mathcal{F}$ is the family of multisets where each multiset is comprised of elements of $N$ and the cardinality of each multiset is at most the cardinality of $N$.  For example, $X\in\mathcal{F}$ where $X=\{2,2,4\}$, you have for each $x\in X$ also that $x\in N$ and that $|X|\leq |N|$.  Notice here that $X\not\in N$ but $|X|\leq |N|$.  With $|x|\leq|N|$ as you defined earlier, it doesn't discount the possibility of $\{2,2,2,\dots,2,4\}$ even in your example.

Comment: For further clarification @Steven if $N=\{1,2,3,4\}$, is $\{1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4\}$ an allowable multiset?  (the difference here being are we constrained to the size of the multiset being smaller or equal to the size of N, or are we constrained to the number of repititions of each number individually being smaller than or equal to the size of N).  If the answer is yes, then TheEmporer's answer is the one you are interested in.  If the answer is no, then my answer is the one you are interested in.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ah. I didn't realize the OP was referring to Multisets (I commented before his post was edited.)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that order does not matter, this is solvable using *Stars-and-Bars*.

Define an ordering of our set of integers $N = \{n_1,n_2,n_3,\dots,n_k\}$

Let $x_i = $the number of times that $n_i$ appears in our multiset for each $i\in [k]$

We are curious then to the number of Dionphantine solutions to $x_1+x_2+\dots+x_k \leq k$

To account for the fact that we are asking about $\leq$ instead of $=$, introduce an additional variable $x_0$ such that $x_0= k - x_1-x_2-\dots-x_k$.

So, then the number of Dionphantine solutions to $x_0+x_1+\dots+x_k = k$ with each $x_i\geq 0$ is then given by the multichoose function (read about the Stars and Bars method from wikipedia to see why) as 
$$\left(\!\!\!\binom{k}{k+1}\!\!\!\right) = \binom{k+(k+1)-1}{(k+1)-1} = \binom{2k}{k}$$

Answer (score 0):

Did I understand correctly? You want the number of multi-sets where each element is an element of $\{1,2,3\dots n\}$ and each element appears at most $n$ times?

To solve this just select how many times you want each of the integers fron $1$ to $n$ to appear in the multiset, this value can be any integer between $0$ and $n$ and so there are $n+1$ choices, since this choice is taken $n$ times the final answer is $(n+1)^n$

Comment: I don't see how this takes order into account.

Comment: Did you read the first paragraph of my answer. I think there is a difference between the size restrictions, you restrict the size of the whole set while I restrict the number of appearances of each element.

Comment: Hmm, I see what you mean now, though I'm still finding the original question worded poorly hence our confusion and contradicting answers.  Given your interpretation then, I agree with your answer.  I'm basing my interpretation from the statement "{2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4} size is bigger than the size of N" where he says "{2,...} size" as opposed to "the number of times two appears is bigger than N".